# Wordpress show bonus content based on url parameter

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide some content based on a tag, let's say the tag "BONUS". Only when users know the 'secret url', these posts/pages are shown. I know this is a very weak security but that's all I need.

mysite.com -> all content, except if it has the BONUS tag

mysite.com/addsomething -> all content including that having the BONUS tag

I'm open to any solution - if there's a plugin it would be great but if I have to program in front end or back end, that's ok too.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways of doing this, would it be an acceptable solution to simply create a page and use a custom page template. I guess it really depends on what kind of extra bonus content you want to show. Another solution could be a query string on the end of the url and and if statement in the page template. If you could provide a little more info on what exactly you want to do and your level of coding ability I'd be in a better position to give you a solution.

Comment: I'm making a portfolio about my work as a videographer. Some projects are a bit too glamorous to show to all visitors. So I want those pages hidden, also in search results and category overviews. I only want to show them to people that I send the mysite.com/addsomething URL so they disclose all that content.

Comment: I've been backend programming since 2000, (PHP since 2010). But I have to find out where this if statement should come within the WP framework in order to filter this content out of the category page when the parameter is not there.

Comment: One way to do this is using separate pages/page templates and categories. For example if you have a portfolio page like www.example.com/portfolio/ that shows only the categories you want to show then a separate page like www.example.com/portfolio/bonus that includes all of the bonus material also. This would involve using custom queries on your page templates to include/exclude the relevant categories also to hide them from search results. Does this sound like a solution that could work for your situation? If so I can give you more info on how to implement it.

Comment: Like I said there's a lot of different ways to do it so it can depend on your specific set up like number of pages you are hiding and how much you've already built, custom/bought theme etc.